# Xamarin IOS CanPerformAction Not Working

Tags: ios, xamarin, copy, xamarin.forms, paste

I'm trying to disabled copy and paste in Entry.

I use CanPerform action inherit from EntryRenderer.

```
public class NEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    public override bool CanPerform(Selector action, NSObject withSender)
    {
        if (action == new Selector("paste:") || action == new Selector("copy:"))
            return false;

        return base.CanPerform(action, withSender);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to hide the **editing menu** from appearing on the `UITextField`:

```
public class NEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    public override bool CanPerform(Selector action, NSObject withSender)
    {
        NSOperationQueue.MainQueue.AddOperation(() => 
        {
            UIMenuController.SharedMenuController.SetMenuVisible(false, false);
        });
        return base.CanPerform(action, withSender);
    }
}
```

> The singleton UIMenuController instance presents the menu interface for the Cut, Copy, Paste, Select, Select All, and Delete commands.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimenucontroller